# How to use *ngFor to loop through 2 columns in a table using Tailwind Css?

Tags: angular, for-loop, tailwind-css, ngfor

I'm trying to create a table and fill the blocks with an *ngFor loop in Angular. This is the original code that just shows it as a list:

```
<ul class="m-2 lg:m-8 pl-8">
          <li *ngFor="let c of otherClasses">
            <menu-link
              [entry]="{
                url: c.external_url,
                site: 'oasis',
                path: ['class', c.slug]
              }"
              >{{ c.title }}</menu-link
            >
          </li>
          <li>
            <a target="_blank" href="https://expium.com/"
              >Atlassian training, offered by our sister company Expium</a
            >
          </li>
        </ul>
```

This is a not so good solution I keep playing around with:

```
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="w-1/2">Col 1</th>
              <th class="w-1/2">Col 2</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td *ngFor="let c of otherClasses">{{ c.title }}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

I'm not sure if I'm completely missing the mark, or if I just need to put the loop in a better place.
[This is what I want the table to eventually look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeb1c.png)

Comment: Do you need to use a table? Try to do it with [Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout), it will be a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="w-1/2">Col 1</th>
          <th class="w-1/2">Col 2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let c of otherClasses;let i = index; let even = even">
          <ng-container *ngIf="even">
              <td>{{otherClasses[i].title}}</td>
              <td>{{otherClasses[i+1].title}}</td>
          </ng-container>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

This should display your table as you want. By using let even we can show two elements of otherClasses per row.

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-ngfor/